# How to fill scrollview width programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a button fill a width of a scrollview programmatically. I made the button programmatically also. scrollView.width does not work, what would I use for the width of the scrollView? Thanks.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let btn1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width:200, height: 50))



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btn1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        btn1.setTitle("1", forState: .Normal)


        scrollView.addSubview(btn1)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: try `scrollView.frame.size.width`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let btn1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width:200, height: 50))



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btn1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        btn1.setTitle("1", forState: .Normal)

        scrollView.addSubview(btn1)

    }
 
    // Add this
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        let newFrame = btn1.frame
        newFrame.size.width = scrollView.bounds.width
        btn1.frame = newFrame
    }
```

}

## Best practice

To get or set the size (width or height) use "bounds" instead of "frame"

To get the origin (x or y) use "frame"

To set or animate the origin (x or y), use "center" instead of "frame"

The value in the center property is always valid, even if scaling or rotation factors have been added to the view’s transform. The same is not true for the value in the frame property, which is considered invalid if the view’s transform is not equal to the identity transform.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:-

1. You can programmatically set the *autolayout* constraints. Just align the left margin and right margin of the button to the scrollview.
2. In the *viewDidLayoutSubviews* method, you can set 
   btn1.frame.size.width = self.tableview.contentSize.width